# How do i make an image responsive but the height stays constant

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know how to do it like this website
http://themeforest.net/item/the-retailer-retina-responsive-woocommerce-theme/full_screen_preview/4287447

Comment: and i want a nightcap, but alas there's work to do.

Comment: Please ask an actual question. We don't want to analyze another website for you.

Comment: Do you want an image who's height changes proportionally to its width?  Or an image who's height stays at a fixed value despite its change in width?

Comment: get ur wallet out and buy this plugin => http://www.themepunch.com/codecanyon/revolution_wp/

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani, that's not helpful. It doesn't answer the question or tell him why he's not getting an answer. You should delete your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that it doesn't stay constant height once the image is scaled too small. It just crops the bottom off when the height goes over 480px. The easiest way to achieve the same would be to do the following:

```
<div style="max-height:480px; overflow: hidden">
    <img src="" style="width:100%" />
</div>
```